# Стоит ли кэшировать?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Привет Всем! Возник вопрос. У меня на сайте практически все кэшируется. Кэшируются: последний комментария, посл. форум, новости и т.д.. Я кэширую таким способом. Скрипт делает запрос раз 5 минут и записывает запрос в определений файл. Суть вопроса: Есть ли смысл кэшировать? На сколько меньше нагрузка или быстрее скорость загрузки. Может там мизерная разница и проще делать через sql?

Сумма размера запроса составляет 8-10 кб. Онлайн каждый день увеличивается, но конечно не геометрической прогрессии. Сейчас онлайн в день 200.

Comment: Какая нагрузка вашего проекта? Практически на 100% уверен, что у вас синдром преждевременной оптимизации... Возможно, я ошибаюсь конечно, но тем не менее...<br>
Кэширование остро необходимо, если у вас большой онлайн и большая база...<br>
В общем, по сути все зависит от проекта, если у вас, например, выборка из таблицы длится 7 секунд, то тогда естественно кешированию быть. В общем, суть в том, что все зависит от масштабов и нагрузки...

Comment: Ну тогда если вы активно продолжаете развивать проект, то ИМХО лучше сосредоточится именно на этом... С оптимизацией, при грамотной структуре кода и БД вы всегда успеете разобраться...

Comment: Значит есть смысл. А есть где-то статистика, где показывает нагрузка сайт и скорость, за который отвечает цикл, функция или оператор. Или есть какой-то скрипт или плагин, который показывает в моем коде, что сколько грузит? Только кроме html, img, css, js.

Comment: Используйте отладчики php кода типа xdebug...<br>
Кстати почему вы решили что есть смысл, если не секрет?

Comment: Так как вижу популярность растет, и почему сразу не сделать)

Comment: А зачем делать когда в этом нет нужды? Или больше нечего?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кэшь - хороший только для вывода большой информации какая не сильно часто обновляется, для всего относительно, разница в скорости и производительности не значительна. Спасибо за комментарии.